# Was there ever a very first Homo sapiens?

Tags: human-evolution

My friend keeps saying that there was a first *Homo sapiens*. Meaning, there was a very first human being that was ever born.

I can't really understand what she means to say from a selection/gene mutation perspective. I can't understand how there would be anything that could be considered the very first human being.

Was there ever a very first, singular human being that could be discerned as such?

Comment: Perhaps she is referring to mitochondrial eve or a "common-ancestor of all people alive today" which is popular with journalists, although it's thought that the human population has never had less than a few thousand common ancestors.

Comment: She means to say the quite literally "someone had to have given birth the the first human baby," just as a logical deduction. There are humans, therefore the must have been a first human baby. So, something gave birth to the very first homo sapien.

Comment: perhaps ask her who made the first car? what was the first pet dog that wasn't a wolf?

Comment: Is there some reason you uncorrected the spelling and capitalization of *Homo sapiens* to "Homo Sapien"? If you insist that is correct please provide a reliable reference that supports that usage. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize it was corrected since no one posted an edit comment. Since I have other misspellings (doing this from my phone), I assumed I had accidentally left it in the lowercase. I didn't realize that the term is lowercase

Comment: Yes, for [binomial names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_nomenclature) the genus is always capitalized and the species (and subspecies) are not. ——— On a phone you should still be able to see that a post has been edited and the word "edited" will be a link that takes you to a page that shows you the edit history. ——— You might find it helpful to take the the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site to become more familiar with how the site works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is important to distinguish "species" as a human system of classification, and "speciation" as a biological process. Except in cases like chromosomal speciation (changes in ploidy), speciation takes a long time. Probably thousands of years between some initial restriction of gene-flow, and fixation of a specific identifiable trait, present in all individuals of a species, and not present in any others. As a human system of classification, the taxonomists who define species would all understand that speciation is a process that occurs over time, although they may make some arbitrary distinction for convenience. For example, a node on a cladogram symbolizes an instantaneous process of species bifurcation, but this is understood to be an unrealistic simplification.

Comment: Thank you. While I didn't have the background, I was pretty sure that was the case.